# Java REST API Complex Query

Tags: java, api, rest

I have a table like this :

[image]

Now I want to create a a **single** REST API endpoint that returns filtered set of data:

1. It should correctly filter any combination of API parameters.
2. All parameters are optional

Look at this example : `GET /api?type=s&max_price=1000&min_price=200&address=Berlin`

I want to be able to filter based each parameter or combination of 2 or parameters.

How should I write my **@RequestParam**? This is a complex query. what is the strategy for this?

Comment: what have you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simple **GET** request like:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/api")
public ReturnDto test(
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "type", defaultValue = "0") String type,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "max_price", defaultValue = "10000") int maxPrice,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "min_price", defaultValue = "0  ") int minPrice,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "address", defaultValue = "") int address
        ) {
}
```

If you don't need the default value, you can remove the `defaultValue` keyword, but then you need to change int to Integer, to allow `null` values.